# How old was Lord Parashurama?

Tags: yuga, parashurama, life-span, chiranjivi

Lord Parashurama believed to be one of the Avatars of God Vishnu. I have seen that Parashuram were present in Ramayana (*When God Ram breaks the God Shiva's blessed Bow to marry Goddess Sita*) as well as in Mahabharatha (*as a teacher who teaches secret and deadliest arts of battle to Bheeshma*). As far as I know, these two epic stories were happened in completely different Yugas.

So, how was Lord Parashurama alive so long? Or is he immortal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He is one of the seven immortals or [Chiranjivi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiranjivi), of Hinduism. The [Kalki Purana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki_Purana) writes that he will re emerge at end time to be the martial guru of Kalki. He will then instruct the final avatar to undertake penance to receive celestial weaponry, required to save mankind at end time.

Comment: It would be more useful if references from puranas are quoted.